# Mapping a a bi-directional relationship between a view and a child table in Entity Framework 6 Code-First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6 Code First and running into trouble trying to to map a two-way relationship between:

```
public class Person //This maps to a view in the database
    {
        [Key]
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("MainPhoneNumber")]
        public int PersonPhonePrimaryId { get; set; }
        public virtual PhoneNumber MainPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
public class PhoneNumber //maps to a table
    {
        [Key]
        public int PersonPhoneId { get; set; }
        public string AreaCode { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNo { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Person")]
        public int PersonId { get; set; } //foreign key in the database
        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Each person has many phone numbers, but there is only one main phone number represented by the MainPhoneNumber property on the Person entity.

The one-to many relationship between Person and PhoneNumber maps correctly, but as soon as I try to map the MainPhoneNumber property on the Person, I get the following exception:

> "message": "Invalid column name 'Person_PersonId'.\r\nInvalid column
>   name 'Person_PersonId'.",
>             "type": "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException"

Is it possible to do this mapping?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Person //This maps to a view in the database
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    public virtual PhoneNumber MainPhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

public class PhoneNumber //maps to a table
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonPhoneId { get; set; }
    public string AreaCode { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}

class Context : DbContext
{

    public Context(DbConnection connection)
        : base(connection, false)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PhoneNumber>().HasOptional(e => e.Person).WithMany(e => e.PhoneNumbers);
    }
}
```

You need to check that Person.MainPhoneNumber.Person == Person because you can't specify this rule with EF.